# Type mismatch WideMemo and LargeInt Delphi clientdataset

Tags: ios, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4, tclientdataset

I'm trying to create an ios app with Delphi xe4 and sqlite.
Reopening ClienDataSet after loading some data I have the message:

> Type mismatch for field 'ct_id', expecting: WideMemo  actual:LargeInt.

Database: SQLITE:

```
....
'CREATE TABLE Contacts ('
+ ' ct_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,'
+ ' ct_type TEXT,'
....
```

then I use a TSqlDataset, TDataSetprovider and ClientDataSet to update table:

```
ClientDataSet.FieldByName('ct_id').AsInteger :=  1; ...
```

TSqlDataset parameters are:

```
Command type : ctQuery
Command text: 'select * from "Contacts"'
```

If table is empty I don't have problems.

Comment: Please review the edit which was attemted on your post (click on the edited some-time-ago  bit) and ensure that you have spelled everything correctly. Also please remove the Someone can help and the Thank you. We know you are looking for an answer, and Thanks is just not the way it is done in the House Style

Comment: Where are the properties for your TSQLDataSet? They determine how/what data is retrieved and we can't see that here.